# Jerky horizontal scroll with javascript wheel event

Tags: javascript, events, scroll

I am working on an application that allows the user to scroll horizontally in 2 ways:

- click and drag
- using the mouse wheel event

The problem is that I can’t get a smooth scroll in the second case.

When I use the mouse wheel the container moves in units of 100 pixels at once, which gives a jerky scroll. Do you know how I could improve this in javascript? Thank you

```
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

        let isDown = false;
        let startX;
        let scrollLeft;

        scrollContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            isDown = true;
            startX = e.pageX - scrollContainer.offsetLeft;
            scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
        });

        scrollContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            isDown = false;
        });

        scrollContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            isDown = false;
        });

        scrollContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if(!isDown) return;
            e.preventDefault();
            const x = e.pageX - scrollContainer.offsetLeft;
            const walk = (x - startX) * 2; //scroll-fast
            scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
        });

        // jerky scroll with wheel
        scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
        });
```

Comment: Every time scroll happens: Do you want container to move less pixels or do you want some scroll animation to end after 100 pixels?

Comment: Have you tried something like  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY / 10;

Comment: Thanks for your answer: the scroll is more fluid with your solution, but it slows it down a lot.